# How shall I design this database?

Tags: sqlite

So I've got to design a table for clients with fields (Id, name, bla, bla, Phone numbers). The last field terrifies me as there is not only one number, but many. I see 3 ways to accomplish this task

1. The field is String. Anytime before an insert, the String array of phone numbers is encoded using a delimiter ';' and thereafter inserted as String.
2. The field is BLOB. The string array is directly stored (no idea if this is possible in sqlite).
3. Create another table for Phone numbers with field (ClientId, PhoneNumber).

What seems the best approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is bad practice to store multiple values in one field, the third option stated is the regular way to go.